# PHP - Convert USD to IQD closest price

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce, currency, price

I have a price number converted from USD to IQD (Iraqi Dinar) according to the exchange rate specified, for example:

```php
// Conversion method
function USD_to_IQD($price){
   $exchangeRate = 1450;
   return round($price * $exchangeRate);
}

$price = 1 // USD
$convertedPrice = USD_to_IQD($price)

// result: 1450 IQD
```

That's all fine for now, I'm getting the price from USD to IQD (my country currency).

But the problem here is, the `converted price` is (1450) and the (450) should be close to either `(250, 500, 750, 1000)` according to the case returned, which is in this case will be closed to (500) then the result will be (1500) as I need.

examples:

```php
$price = 1930 // IQD, should be 2000
$price = 1600 // IQD, should be 1750
$price = 1030 // IQD, should be 1250
...
```

according to the case (the converted price)!

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this with little calculation alongwith `ceil` function.

I've kept 250 static as it is the multiple of all your options.

```
echo ceil(1930 / 250) * 250; // Output: 2000
echo ceil(1600 / 250) * 250; // Output: 1750
echo ceil(1030 / 250) * 250; // Output: 1250
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it worked as I need and as it should be <3

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method:

```
// Conversion method
function USD_to_IQD($price){
   $exchangeRate = 1450;
   $step = 250;

   $calculatedPrice = $price * $exchangeRate;
   $surplus = ($calculatedPrice % $step);
   return $calculatedPrice + ($surplus ? ($step - $surplus) : 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but it is not as I need! .. Yash's answer is exactly what I need and as it should be with my examples,
Thank you again <3